# ASUS P5B - is it possible to use Fast Start and still boot from CD?

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios

I have a ASUS P5B running Windows 8.

When I **shut down** Windows 8 and try to cold-boot Acronis from a CD, I cannot, even though the BIOS is set to boot from CD. Instead, Windows boots.

However, if I **restart* Windows 8 with the CD in, Acronis boots fine.

Also, if I turn off Fast Start in Windows 8, I can boot from the CD all the time.

Is it possible to use Fast Start and still boot from CD?

Answer (score 2):

'Fast Start' (aka: Hybrid Shutdown, aka: Hybrid Boot) logs off all users and then *hibernates* the machine.

Waking from hibernation skips (doesn't use) the BIOS start-up boot sequence.

If you want to do a full shutdown at any point (without turning Hybrid Shutdown off), open a command line and run `shutdown -s -t 0` to immediately shutdown the system, without using the hybrid shutdown.

More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/olivnie/archive/2012/12/14/windows-8-fast-boot.aspx) and [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/).